# Create Image or Bitmap in console application - can't seem to find System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, bitmap, console-application

I'm trying to create an image or bitmap from a camera bitstream that I will be (hopefully) passing to the browser via a websocket. The application I'm building is a console app as I didn't think there would be a need for this app to have a GUI. Now I'm having trouble creating/accessing Image and Bitmap classes - System.Drawing doesn't seem to exist and I'm not sure why. When I try `using System.Drawing` I get the error `The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` What's the best way to create a bitmap in a console application, and is there a reason I seem to be unable to load System.Drawing?

Code:

```
private void Kinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (ColorImageFrame frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (frame != null)
        {
            byte[] pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
            frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
            //how do we create a bitmap here and pass it off to chrome?

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate assemblies referenced in your project?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to add Reference to the system.Drawing.Dll in your project.

Right click on Project, add reference and find System.Drawing.DLL and add reference.

EDIT: 
You will find it under Assemblies->Framework->System.Drawing

Comment: Argh, the shame, it burns. Thank you.

Comment: In .Net Core, go to Nuget Packages and add System.Drawing.Primitives

Answer (score 5):

Add System.Drawing.dll as reference assembly to your project.

Comment: Knew it was something obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

include System.Drawing.dll to the reference
1) you can download it from http://www.dllme.com/dll/download/7139/System.Drawing.dll